# How to remove array index from php array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

My function is waiting response in array as in format below:

```
main[insert][id][insert]='some value'
```

I have prepared loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
$data_array[] = array(
"insert" => array($data[$i]["id"] => 
array ("insert" => "some value"; }
```

However after I run it I have such values:

```
main[insert][//i value from 0 to 99][id][insert] = "some value"
main[insert][0][005][insert] = "some value"
main[insert][1][008][insert] = "some value"
```

Everything looks good I just don't need this loop `i` values, I just need values without it of such view: `main[insert][id][insert]='some value'`

Comment: What is the value of `$data`?

Comment: @MA But I take values from other array in a loop. So it changes dynamically, there are different values of id for every separate $i. And it works perfect as I have different ids, but I don't need [$i] in it.

Comment: Can you paste content of `$data` array?

Comment: @MA $data[$i]["id"] gives me different ids for every loop stage. It works perfect.

Comment: $data = { [name]=>"name",...., ["id"] => "id"} - so it gives: main[insert][0][005][insert] = "some value"
main[insert][1][008][insert] = "some value" where [0]... [i] is my loop's index.

Comment: The code you have written should work fine and I am helpless unless you tell more what is returned by `$data[$i]["id"]`?

Comment: Also, you have syntax errors.

Comment: @MA Thank you for your efforts to support me in it. I need to make a fresh view to it because I am a little be confused. Once again appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your loop with the below code:

It will be great if you could provide the structure of `$data`

```
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {

  $data_array[][ "insert"] = [ 
                                $data[$i]["id"] => ["insert" => "some value"]
                               ]
}
```

edit:
From your solution in comment: @VAPPM

```
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) { 
  $current_id=$data[$i]['id']; 
  $data_array['insert'][$current_id]['insert'] = "some value"; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you for your support. Wish all the best in your coding.

Comment: @VAPPM This code won't even run due to syntax errors! How can you accept this answer?

Comment: @Nick I have updated the answer. Please check it now.

Comment: @Nick But this worked in my case, I have just simplified code by removing one array as dexter has proposed and now I have what I wanted.

Comment: @VAPPM The code still has syntax errors and produces **exactly** the same result as your original code after those errors are fixed.

Comment: @Nick it worked in my case: for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) { $current_id=$data[$i]['id'];
$data_array['insert'][$current_id]['insert'] = "some value"; }

Comment: @VAPPM that code is nothing like this answer. So I don't understand why you accepted it. You should have posted your working code as an answer instead and accepted that.

Comment: @Nick, I am new on a platform. dexter gave me direction to catch a solution, so that's why I suppose that his answer is similar with my solution. Anyway, appreciate your attention to an issue and your advice. I really impressed how friendly is IT-community.